# TemplateResolver not adding to TemplateEngine

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I do the following code in my configuration bean for the templateEngine, only one is added (first one) see 15 Chaining Template Resolvers:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

```
    //full extract below /*>>><<<*/
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(javascriptTemplateResolver());
```

Additional Information:

*The core of my issue I was to be able to use HTML, Javascript and CSS with webmvc and found Thymeleaf; should I use something else instead, and  if so what should I use!?*
A good alternative to THYMELEAF may be better, as I'll have to add RequestMapping for each file this way.

Currently I have set up HTML pages to be considered in WEB-INF/ and finds it fine. I added a js file in head in the normal way, but I get a 500 error returned on execution.
I see in F12 that "http://localhost:8080/ajax.js" is being called and I have a controller set up for this and hits my System.out.

It dose work if I use either th:inline="javascript and have logic in script tags. It also works if I have *.js files in WEB-INF/ with *.html. However I should be able to organize my files in the normal way with /js /css folders respectively.

I think the issue is with the setting of the second TemplateResolver.

```
    @Controller
    public class JavascriptController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "ajax.js", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String main(Model model) {

            System.out.println("entered js controller!");
            return "ajax.js";
        }
    }
```

WebAppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ash.boot.mvcexample")
public class WebAppConfig implements  WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");        
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving Javascript")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        javascriptTemplateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/js/");
        javascriptTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        javascriptTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".js");  
        javascriptTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("JAVASCRIPT");
        javascriptTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return javascriptTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(javascriptTemplateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(null);
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }    

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    entered js controller!
    [2m2018-06-24 20:54:00.020[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m1704[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36morg.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine            [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "ajax.js": An error happened during template parsing (template: "WEB-INF/ajax.js")

    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "WEB-INF/ajax.js")
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parse(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:92) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:354) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "WEB-INF/ajax.js" could not be resolved
        at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ClassLoaderTemplateResource.reader(ClassLoaderTemplateResource.java:130) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parse(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:156) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 40 common frames omitted

    [2m2018-06-24 20:54:00.026[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m1704[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "WEB-INF/ajax.js")] with root cause

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "WEB-INF/ajax.js" could not be resolved
        at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ClassLoaderTemplateResource.reader(ClassLoaderTemplateResource.java:130) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parse(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:156) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:92) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:354) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Good way of telling SpringMVC where my files are located. This was done my using ResourceHandlerRegistry see code snippet.
I like this method due the fact I don't have to make controller for each file anymore. 
Solution was found here: https://memorynotfound.com/adding-static-resources-css-javascript-images-thymeleaf/
I also later saw that there is a Spring version on Thymeleaf and a normal version, and I'm guessing the code i was using wasn't supported in spring.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/webjars/**",
            "/img/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                    "classpath:/WEB-INF/img/",
                    "classpath:/WEB-INF/css/",
                    "classpath:/WEB-INF/js/");
}
```